# Add text to a video with effects using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I need to add text in between a video. I have seen `drawtext` and seems it wont give effects to the text to be displayed.

My intention is to show a text within a box with some background to that box which should fly from left to right in between a video at a particular time. Is it possible with FFMPEG? I have tried different options with drawtext and nothing seems to be working. Any ideas on how to make it?

or is it possible to achieve by combining imagemagick and FFMPEG command?

Comment: What do you mean by "between a video"?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I am creating a video using set of images. So I need to write some comments/name of the person in the image. The box displaying the name/comments should appear with some effects like flying in from left to right.

Comment: The [drawtext filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext) can allow movement of the text and can also allow you to place a box behind the text.

Comment: ffmpeg's drawtext can do some minor effects, like a box around it IIRC [you can control the location of the box using ffmpeg's "eval" type syntax] gl